# .htaccess rewrite everything, without exception

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I want to redirect all requests to a directory to its index.php.

Inside the folder `/wp-content/themes/sometheme/qr/` I placed this [.htaccess](/questions/tagged/.htaccess):

```
RewriteEngine on

RewriteBase /wp-content/themes/sometheme/qr/

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f 
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d 
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-l

RewriteRule .* index.php [L]
```

As far as I know, this should rewrite everything to the `index.php` in the qt-folder.

When I open `/wp-content/themes/sometheme/qr/test/sometest.txt` in the browser, as expected, the `index.php` is executed. But for the url `/wp-content/themes/sometheme/qr/http%3A%2F%2Fwww.eample.com%2Fwp-content%2Fuploads%2F2014%2F03%2Fdemo.vcf` it does not, instead, I get a 404 error.

This elves me a little confused, I expected `.*` to match absolutely every url possible. Why does it not get redirected?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay, I think I found the answer. Apparently my Apache was not happy about the `%2F` in my url and discarded them as invalid even before invoking any modules.

The only way (to my knowledge) to solve this was to not encode the parameter, so my url looks like this now:

```
/wp-content/themes/sometheme/qr/http://www.eample.com/wp-content/uploads/2014/03/demo.vcf
```

In my opinion, this url looks even more wrong with its `http://` stuck in the middle. So if anybody knows a way around this, shoot now!